# Mysql stopped working, the server quit without updating PID file

Tags: mysql, innodb, pid

I'm working on a Mac Yosemite and in my local environment I have mysql-5.6.21 installed through homebrew. It suddendly stopped working. I was actually browsing one of the websites I'm working on and I got a database error. At first it said that one of the table was set as read only and then I noticed that I couldn't start mysql anymore.

When I run `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe` I get this:

```
150716 12:31:23 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/Mac-Sportello.err'.
150716 12:31:23 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
150716 12:31:23 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/Mac-Sportello.pid ended
```

And the .err file contains this:

```
150716 12:19:08 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
2015-07-16 12:19:08 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-07-16 12:19:08 23754 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql/data/ is case insensitive
2015-07-16 12:19:08 23754 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
^G/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13 - Permission denied)
2015-07-16 12:19:08 23754 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2015-07-16 12:19:08 23754 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-07-16 12:19:08 23754 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-07-16 12:19:08 23754 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-07-16 12:19:08 23754 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-07-16 12:19:08 23754 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-07-16 12:19:08 23754 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-07-16 12:19:08 23754 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-07-16 12:19:08 23754 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-07-16 12:19:08 23754 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-07-16 12:19:08 23754 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 501272750 and 501272750 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 502794898 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-07-16 12:19:08 23754 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-07-16 12:19:08 23754 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-07-16 12:19:08 23754 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-07-16 12:19:08 23754 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages
2015-07-16 12:19:08 23754 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
```

Then lot of errors specific to database tables, like this:

```
2015-07-16 12:19:09 23754 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table database/wp_commentmeta in the InnoDB data dictionary has
tablespace id 115, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This
may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but
 the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
```

And then:

```
2015-07-16 12:33:21 32057 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.21 started; log sequence number 502794898
2015-07-16 12:33:21 32057 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-07-16 12:33:21 32057 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-07-16 12:33:21 32057 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-07-16 12:33:21 32057 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-07-16 12:33:21 32057 [ERROR] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/usr/local/mysql/data/Mac-Sportello.pid' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2015-07-16 12:33:21 32057 [ERROR] Can't start server: can't create PID file: Permission denied
150716 12:33:21 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/Mac-Sportello.pid ended
```

It seems that the errors are related to InnoDB.

I read this page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html

But nothing seems to be related to my case. I didn't do any of that operations and it seems to have broken in the middle of nothing.

I had a look at other similar questions and tried removing the `.err` file or manually creating the `.pid` file, but, again, nothing worked.

What can I do?

EDIT:
I decided to completely remove mysql and install it again. Before doing it I copied the directories containing the databases. So, after installing it again mysql actually works. Then I copied one of the databases inside the new mysql directory. It is loaded but none of the InnoDB tables work and in the mysql log there are these errors:

```
2015-07-16 15:30:58 2215 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table database/table from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
```

Comment: please post the permissions of the files you copied into your mysql directory. also confirm that the mysql directory copied into is in fact the return of `show variables where Variable_name ='datadir'`

Comment: "permission denied" -- How are you invoking mysqld?